# How do I change the View's visibility based on another View's animation in a custom layout?

Tags: android

I created a custom RelativeLayout called WheelLayout which contains two ImageViews. The first View, WheelView, is a custom View that calls RotateAnimation a couple times.

WheelView has a custom interface called WheelListener.

```
 public interface WheelListener {
    public void wheelStarted();
    public void wheelStoppedOnSlice(int sliceNum);
 }
```

In WheelView, I implement Animation.AnimationListener as follows:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    mListener.wheelStarted();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        mListener.wheelStoppedOnSlice(mCurrentSlice);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}
```

Where mListener is a WheelListener.

WheelLayout implements WheelListener like so:

```
@Override
public void wheelStarted() {
   mSliceImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void wheelStoppedOnSlice(int sliceNum) {
    mSliceImage.setBackgroundResource(mSlices[sliceNum]);
    mSliceImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

When WheelView animates, I expect to see mSliceImage disappear and WheelView to continue its animation to completion. Instead, neither occurs. My WheelView does not animate and mSliceImage does not disappear.

However, after the animation would finish, I *do* see mSliceImage change its background resource.

I also tried the same thing where mSliceImage was *not* a child of custom layout and it worked perfectly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

problem is you use "View.GONE". you should use "View.INVISIBLE"

try this

```
 @Override
  public void wheelStarted() {
     mSliceImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
```

Comment: View.INVISIBLE does not make my mSliceImage disappear but does allow my WheelView to animate. I've put a Log call in there, so I know the function gets hit, but no dice.